# How can I search for contacts without a specific Activity Type?

Tags: civicase, activities, search

I have created an Activity Type "Ceremonial" to attach to Contacts via Cases, which I am using to track qualifications we have awarded, honours we have granted and Fellows that we have admitted to membership. Each has an opportunity for ceremonial admission to the organisation. I am now trying to find those Contacts with Cases of Status="Successful" to which an Activity "Ceremonial" needs to be attached (so we can track whether the Individual has participated in a Ceremonial for their Award). I have attached the Activity to some Cases as they have been processed, but not all, and so want an efficient method to identify the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with search kit as below. The key part is the "With (Optional)" for the activity restricted by type and then the "activity id is empty" in the where clause. Obviously use "Ceremonial" instead of Meeting for the activity type, and you can add case status = Successful in the where clause.

[image]

As an aside, one of the earliest features in civicase was an "audit" feature that was meant for this kind of thing - finding and acting on cases where part of the workflow was incomplete. But it was a bit of an experiment and never panned out.

Comment: Thank you so much; that is such a helpful response. What an amazing community!